# Organizing query results into groups using the group by clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by

What would be a valid GROUP BY clause for the following SELECT list:

```
SELECT Pub_ID, Type, Max (Price)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to GROUP BY both Pub_ID and Type, as they are in the selection criteria, but not within an aggregate function.

```
SELECT Pub_ID, Type, MAX(Price) FROM mytable GROUP BY Pub_ID, Type
```

Comment: It's not a competition ... but I won nevertheless ;)

Comment: Sometimes is :) Anyway I gave +1 also to Frank because both of you are right.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Pub_ID, Type, max(Price)
from your_table
group by Pub_ID, Type
```